# Find in Files - Number per file

Tags: emeditor

In EMEditor, is there a way to get the number of occurrences of a "find in files" search *per file*? In other words, it finds 10,000 "hits" across 25 files, I'd like to know that 1200 where in file1 etc.
Notepad++ does a great job of this by allowing you to collapse the results by file and showing a summary for each, but I haven't seen a way to get the information in EMEditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **Find in Files**, you can run this macro while the results document is active. Save this code as, for instance,  `statistics.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, do **Find in Files**, and select **Run** in the **Macros** menu while the results document is active.

```
// Creates statistics from Find in Files Results.  
// 2020-06-27
Redraw = false;
sOutput = "";
y = 1;
yMax = document.GetLines();
for( ;; ) {
    document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, 1, y++ );
    document.selection.Mode = eeModeStream | eeModeKeyboard;
    bFound = document.selection.Find("\\(\\d+?\\)\\:",eeFindNext | eeFindReplaceCase | eeFindReplaceRegExp,0);
    document.selection.Mode = eeModeStream;
    if( !bFound ) {
        break;
    }
    sFile = document.selection.Text;
    n = sFile.lastIndexOf("(");
    sFile = sFile.substr( 0, n );
    nCount = 1;
    for( ;; ) {
        document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, 1, y );
        sLine = document.GetLine( y );
        if( sLine.length > sFile.length && sLine.substr( 0, sFile.length ) == sFile ) {
            ++nCount;
            ++y;
        }
        else {
            sOutput += sFile + "\t" + nCount + "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
document.selection.Mode = eeModeStream;
Redraw = true;
editor.NewFile();
document.write( sOutput );
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4471);  // switch to TSV mode
```